# Retrieving name of a button in Enyo

Tags: javascript, webos

I am loading images dynamically in a for loop. I have a click event for those images. How to retrieve the name of the image that was clicked?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how you're doing things (some sample code might help) but why not assign a unique id (using the loop counter) to each image and then checking the id in the onclick handler for the element that sent the event?

Answer (score 0):

Two parameters are passed in the onclick, one is the originator of the click and the other is the event. They're both Objects. `inSender` contains things like the name, the owner of it, all it's children, etc...

```
onclick: "imageClicked",
imageClicked: function (inSender, inEvent) {
}
```